# Python Multiprocessing How can I make script faster?

Tags: multithreading, python-multiprocessing

Python 3.6

I am writing a script to automate me checking to make sure all the links on a website for work.

I have a version of it but it runs slow because the python interpreter is only running one request at a time.
I imported selenium to pull the links down in a list. I started with a list of 41000 links. I got rid of the duplicates now I am down to 7300 links in my list.  I am using the request module to just check for the response code.  I know multiprocessing is the answer just see a bunch of different methods. Which is the best for my needs?

The only thing I need to keep in mind I can't run to many threads at once so I don't send our webserver threads on our server sky high with request.

Here is the function that checks the links with the python requests module that I am trying to speed up:

```
def check_links(y):
    for ii in y:
        try:
            r = requests.get(ii.get_attribute('href'))
            rc = r.status_code
            print(ii.get_attribute('href'), ' ', rc)
        except Exception as e:
            logf.write(str(e))
        finally:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to apply the same function to all the items in a list, you just need to use a process pool, and map over you inputs. Here is a simple example:

```
from multiprocessing import pool

def square(x):
    return {x: x**2}

p = pool.Pool()
results = p.imap_unordered(square, range(10))

for r in results:
    print(r)
```

In the example I use `imap_unordered`, but also look at `map` and `imap`. You should choose the one that matches your needs the best.